# Reference Request: Rate at which Training Error goes to 0

Tags: machine-learning, references, training-error

Looking for references on which training error goes to 0. As an example, suppose that we have a linear model $y = X \beta_0 + \epsilon,$ where $\beta_0$ is bounded and each row of $X$ is generated according to a distribution of finite support (or perhaps some distribution with light tails). Suppose also that the noise $\epsilon_i$ are iid $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2).$ We estimate some $\hat{\beta}_n$ (the subscript $n$ denotes that this is a function of the data) using the normal least squares method, and we want to know how fast $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(y_i - X_i \hat{\beta} \right)^2 $$ decreases.

I figure this is a standard problem in statistical learning theory, but somehow I can't find any references on this. The specific case I care about is different from this, but anything, even starting from simple examples, would be great!